# What's the symbol of both 1 and 0?

Tags: terminology

> Computers process everything using "true" (1) and "false" (0).
>
> But quantum computers use "true", "false", and "both true and false"

What's the symbol used to describe both? (e.g. true: 1)

Comment: I have no idea, but you seem to use "1" ;)

Comment: 0.5 or 1/2  perhaps ?

Comment: @Criggie, I always thought the symbol was `?!`  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The state of a qubit (or a set of qubits) is basically the probabilities of it being in each state. There's more to it, though: those "probabilities" can be negative or even [complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number). The sum of the squares of the *probability amplitudes* has to add up to 1. One way to represent these states inline is [bra-ket notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation).

For a single qubit that's definitely on, you could write its state as `|1>`, or more explicitly `1|1> + 0|0>`. The probability of it being set is 1 (100%) and the probability of it being clear is 0. `-|1>` is also a legitimate state, since (-1)<sup>2</sup> + 0<sup>2</sup> is also 1. The latter qubit is in a different phase than the former. One that's equally likely to be on or off *could* be `(1/√2)(|0> + |1>)`. (The one-over-root-of-two is distributed to both states.)

Keep in mind that there are infinitely many states that a given qubit could be in.

Further reading: [Grover's Quantum Search Algorithm](http://twistedoakstudios.com/blog/Post2644_grovers-quantum-search-algorithm), a really good introduction to quantum circuits.

Comment: Strictly, what you call "probability" is a *probability amplitude*, the real *probability* being the squared modulus of it. Then the *probabilities* add up to 1.